# Rails jquery native vs rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using jquery more and more.  But, one thing confuses me.

What benefit do you get from using a rails gem that implements a jquery module, over just installing the pieces without the gem?

For instance bootstrap-editable-rails for x-editable.  Or twitter-bootstrap-rails for Bootstrap.

Thanks!

Comment: It is too much work for jquery ui, bootstrap and fancybox... They have lots of images and all are targeting paths like ../. You have to replace relative paths to asset_paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I don't need to download them manually and they work seamlessly with asset pipeline right away.
- Since it's just a gem, I can use Bundler to take care of updating, checking for new version, resolving dependencies.
- They usually provide some sort of integration with Rails. Take a look at the `twitter-bootstrap-rails` gem. It provides generators for layouts, scaffolds, helpers for working with breadcrumb etc.